# MySQL Grouping OR and AND clauses

Tags: mysql

So the producer table schema is like this:

```
producer_id = int PK
producer_name = varchar
is_restaurant = boolean
is_farm = boolean
is_distributor = boolean
```

and I want a query that does this:

> select all producers whose producer_id
>   are in (11895, 11976, 11457) which is
>   either a farm, a restaurant or a
>   distributor

I have this:

```
SELECT `pd`.`producer_id` AS producer_id, `pd`.`producer` AS producer, `pd`.`is_restaurant`, `pd`.`is_restaurant_chain`, `pd`.`is_farm`, `pd`.`is_farmers_market`, `pd`.`is_distributor`, `pd`.`is_manufacture`, `ad`.`address_id`, `ad`.`address`, `ad`.`state_id`, `ad`.`city`, `ad`.`city_id`, `ad`.`country_id`, `ad`.`zipcode`, `ad`.`latitude`, `ad`.`longitude`, `cu`.`custom_url` AS custom_url
FROM (`producer` AS pd)
JOIN `address` AS ad ON `pd`.`producer_id`=`ad`.`producer_id`
LEFT JOIN `custom_url` AS cu ON `cu`.`producer_id`=`pd`.`producer_id`
WHERE `is_farm` = 1
OR `is_distributor` = 1
OR `is_restaurant` = 1
AND `pd`.`producer_id` IN ('181176', '181180', '176080', '5') 
GROUP BY `ad`.`address_id`
LIMIT 10
```

but the query only applies the WHERE conditions for is_farm, is_distributor and is_restaurant and does not apply the AND clause for producer_id.

I was wondering if I could use a subquery to do "is either a restaurant a distributor or a farm" and just insert it in the query with an AND clause.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is that in SQL, `AND` takes precedence over `OR`, so you just need brackets:

```
SELECT `pd`.`producer_id` AS producer_id, `pd`.`producer` AS producer, `pd`.`is_restaurant`, `pd`.`is_restaurant_chain`, `pd`.`is_farm`, `pd`.`is_farmers_market`, `pd`.`is_distributor`, `pd`.`is_manufacture`, `ad`.`address_id`, `ad`.`address`, `ad`.`state_id`, `ad`.`city`, `ad`.`city_id`, `ad`.`country_id`, `ad`.`zipcode`, `ad`.`latitude`, `ad`.`longitude`, `cu`.`custom_url` AS custom_url
FROM (`producer` AS pd)
JOIN `address` AS ad ON `pd`.`producer_id`=`ad`.`producer_id`
LEFT JOIN `custom_url` AS cu ON `cu`.`producer_id`=`pd`.`producer_id`
WHERE (`is_farm` = 1 -- NOTE: Opening bracket to bracket up your OR terms together
OR `is_distributor` = 1
OR `is_restaurant` = 1) -- NOTE: Closing bracket
AND `pd`.`producer_id` IN ('181176', '181180', '176080', '5') 
GROUP BY `ad`.`address_id`
LIMIT 10
```

Corollary:

In SQL `A OR B OR C AND D` is parsed as `(A OR (B OR (C AND D)))`. Applying brackets will correct this common error, ie `(A OR B OR C) AND D`.

Remember: When mixing `AND` and `OR` terms, always use brackets!

Comment: hm...any idea how I can make this work with CI's Active Record?

Comment: if you have no control over SQL syntax, try creating a view that has an extra column: `create view producer_plus as select *, is_restaurant or is_farm or is_distributor as is_producer from producer`. You will still be able to update it (because it's not a join), but you won't be able to write to the calculated column of course

Comment: This answer almost sidetracked my a bit, in fact `AND` takes precedence as common in other languages.

Comment: @hlev ummmm... oops! Yeah - that's what I meant. My example was correct though. I've fixed up the error. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT `pd`.`producer_id` AS producer_id, `pd`.`producer` AS producer, `pd`.`is_restaurant`, `pd`.`is_restaurant_chain`, `pd`.`is_farm`, `pd`.`is_farmers_market`, `pd`.`is_distributor`, `pd`.`is_manufacture`, `ad`.`address_id`, `ad`.`address`, `ad`.`state_id`, `ad`.`city`, `ad`.`city_id`, `ad`.`country_id`, `ad`.`zipcode`, `ad`.`latitude`, `ad`.`longitude`, `cu`.`custom_url` AS custom_url
FROM (`producer` AS pd)
JOIN `address` AS ad ON `pd`.`producer_id`=`ad`.`producer_id`
LEFT JOIN `custom_url` AS cu ON `cu`.`producer_id`=`pd`.`producer_id`
WHERE `pd`.`producer_id` IN ('181176', '181180', '176080', '5')
AND (`is_distributor` = 1 OR `is_restaurant` = 1 OR `is_farm` = 1)
GROUP BY `ad`.`address_id`
LIMIT 10
```